# Typo3 RealUrl + tt_news -> shorten URL

Tags: typo3, tt-news, realurl

for my tt_news entries, realurl generates links like:

`www.mydomain.com/announcements/news/news/article/date/2013/06/26/a_very_long_filename_which_is_horrible.html`

so i try to get my typo3 to generate something like this:

`www.mydomain.com/news/short_title.html`

but I have no clue how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Merec's solution is some option, de facto you can do the trick without any single line of coding.

1. Place the 'news' page dedicated for single view in the root tree (not in branch `Announcements` > `News` > `News`)
2. Use tt_news' config to remove dates from URL -> [check the manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/tt_news/3.4.0/view/1/4/), search for `HRdates` options, to avoid them.
3. If required use [`fixedPostVars`](http://www.dmitry-dulepov.com/2008/05/realurl-made-easy-part-1.html) to make the URL's as short as possible on given (single) page.

Also you have two options for `horrible_long_title.html` - first is using additional field in for `tt_news` where you can restrict the length in the BackEnd ie. to 100 chars...

second probably better solution  is allowing to use all characters by changing the RealURL config:

```
'lookUpTable' => array(
    'table'               => 'tx_ttnews', // I don't remember now if it's correct tt_news' table...
    'maxLength'           => 9999, // By default it's 100
    'id_field'            => 'uid',
    'alias_field'         => 'title',
    // other config
),
```

Comment: While your answer addresses removal of RealURL keywords and some page titles from the URL, it doesn't address the long titles of articles.

Comment: @cascaval what do yo mean ?

Comment: I mean that your answer doesn't address the change from "a_very_long_filename_which_is_horrible.html" to "short_title.html".

Comment: @cascaval it can be done with `maxLength` config in RU, check my edit pls.

Comment: Good! :-) Though, which way is better to achieve short titles is a matter of opinion. Automatic shortening will result in weird titles in the URL (e.g. "a_very_long_filename_which.html").

Comment: no, no, automatic shortening is worst option I prefer using full title (with overridden `maxLength`) or just by limiting it in TCA. Of course - if client's will is to make two fields for long and short title - it's possible as a Merec (and me too :) ) described, but from my personal experience it's rather rare situation. I observe my clients instances and can see that if additional RU field isn't required in 99.9% it's just blank...

Comment: Sure, full well chosen title is the best. My point is that if shortening is required, custom chosen short titles in a separate field will give better results than automatic shortening.

Comment: Separate field (let's name it `speaking`) is better option, using JS you can even copy the value of the `title` to `speaking` if user will leave it blank.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to create a small extension which extends the tt_news entries by a field which can be used as alternative for generating the title.

Realurl uses the field `title` by default to generate the article-url. The field that will be used can be modified in your `realurl.conf`.

Comment: thank you, but tt_news doesen't have the option to add an alternative string, I could refer to, so I hacked the class.tx_realurl file to truncate all unique aliases, but I have another Problem:

Comment: apears: as soon as I try to remove the date from the link, the t_news parameters reapear

Comment: @Merec, I can't agree with you, creating additional extensions is redundant here...

Comment: @biesior: Merec's answer tries to address one of the problems that you left out in your answer and I wouldn't say it's "redundant" because any solution based on automatic shortening of long news titles will probably result in weird titles in the URL (e.g. "a_very_long_filename_which.html").